# asmx web service & C# console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have an ASMX web service written in C# code using .net Framework 3.5 version.

and I have another C# console Application project consists of many classes and using wordNet Library.

I want to add the console project to web service project, I try to put the folder of console application in the App_Code folder in the web service and try to make an object of class that define in console project but it doesn't work

it says that I missing an Assembly reference !!

can any one help me on that

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to move the contents of one project into the other project.

In the web service project, right click references.

Add reference -> Projects -> Select your project.

Now you just need the appropriate `using` directives in your web service classes.

Although I'm not sure why you're trying to add classes for a console application into a web service project; are you sure it's not the opposite?

Comment: I do as you say, but when I click Add references-> projects I didn't find anythings !

Comment: Have you added both projects to the solution? It sounds like you need to go and learn how to use Visual Studio.